# Question about angular velocity?

Tags: calculus, vectors, physics

If $z=r\cos\theta +ir\sin \theta$, show that $\dfrac{dz}{dt}=r\dfrac{d\theta}{dt}(-\sin\theta+i\cos \theta)$ and that if $\dfrac{d\theta}{dt}$ is constant, then $\arg\dfrac{dz}{dt}=\theta-\pi/2$.

I managed to do everything apart from the argument, which I calculated to be $\theta+\pi/2$ instead. Can anyone help?

The answer says arg(-sinx+icosx)=arctan(cosx/-sinx)=arctan(-cotx)=-arctan(cotx)=-arctan(tan(pi/2‌​-x))=-(pi/2-x)=x-pi/2. What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Can you show your work? Also, this becomes much easier if you use the polar form for $z$.

Comment: I think you are correct

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought if r*dtheta/dz is constant then arg(dz/dt)=arg(-sintheta+icostheta)=arg(cistheta*i)=arg(cistheta)+argi=theta+pi/2 but the questions asks for minus instead? Did I do something wrong or is the question just wrong?

Comment: The answer says arg(-sinx+icosx)=arctan(cosx/-sinx)=arctan(-cotx)=-arctan(cotx)=-arctan(tan(pi/2‌​-x))=-(pi/2-x)=x-pi/2. What is wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

$z=r\cos(\theta) + ir\sin(\theta) = re^{i\theta}$

$\frac{dz}{dt}=rie^{i\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt} = re^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}e^{i\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt} = r\frac{d\theta}{dt}e^{i(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2})}$

Therefore, arg$\frac{dz}{dt}= \theta + \frac{\pi}{2}$ and you are correct.

Comment: The answer says arg(-sinx+icosx)=arctan(cosx/-sinx)=arctan(-cotx)=-arctan(cotx)=-arctan(tan(pi/2-x))=-(pi/2-x)=x-pi/2. What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: @JohnSmith The problem is that $-\cot(x)$ can be either $\tan(x+\frac{\pi}{2})$ or $\tan(x-\frac{\pi}{2})$. How did the author of the solution choose?